# What are the generators of the signed symmetric group $B_n$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, symmetry

Consider the set $A_n=\{-n,-(n-1),-(n-2),\cdots,-1,1,\cdots, n-1,n\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let G be a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{A_n}$ defined as follow: $G=\{\sigma \in S_{A_n}| \forall x \in A_n, \sigma(-x)= -\sigma(x)\}$.

I think $G$ can be generated by the set formed by the transpositions $(i , -i), 1\le i \le n$ and $(1,2)(-1,-2), (1,2, \cdots, n)(-1,-2, \cdots, -n)$ but I don't know if it is an irredundant set of generators or even a minimal subset of generators.

What is an example of irredundant set of generators of $G$?

What is the size of the smallest irredundant set of generators of $G$?

G is also known as the signed symmetric group, denoted $B_n$.

Comment: in your first question do you mean "minimal set of generators" as we know they are not unique (for example $S_m$ is generated by m 2-cycles although the minimal size of generating set is 2)

Comment: I mean an irredundant set of generators

Comment: The group is $C_2 \wr S_n$.

Comment: Concerning your thoughts, $(1,2)$ and $(1,2,\ldots,n)$ are not in the group. Replace that by $(1,2)(-1,-2)$ and $(1,2,\ldots,n)(-1,-2,\ldots,-n)$. You only need one of the transpositions $(i,-i)$, because they are all conjugate under powers of $(1,2,\ldots,n)(-1,-2,\ldots,-n)$. So that gives you an irredundant generating set of size $3$. The problem remains can the group be generated by two elements. (The answer is yes, but that is more difficult.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks! If I could show that it can be generated by 2 elements even without explicitely exhibit these elements it will be sufficient for me.

Comment: Another irredundant generating set is given by the usual Coxeter generators from $S_n$ together with $(-1\ 1)$. That this is irredundant is a standard exercise for Coxeter groups.